# Implementing RabbitMQ in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, rabbitmq

I need to use RabbitMQ in one of my projects. On googling I got to know that the library for RabbitMQ is not compatible with BlackBerry. In some posts in StackOverFlow itself someone has suggested to use STOMP protocol in J2ME as RabbitMQ supports STOMP upon adding some plugins. But I couldn't find a library for STOMP in J2ME as well.

Has anyone used RabbitMQ in Blackberry? Any help will be much appreciated. 
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I converted the Gozirra Stomp Java Client code for J2ME you can download it from

https://github.com/rifatdover/RabbitMQStompConnectorForBlackberry

Comment: Thank you so much Rifat. :)

Answer (score 1):

Build a more traditional web interface for RabbitMQ, then have the BlackBerry client code talk to the web interface.

Comment: Thank you for your response Michael. But if I do like the way you said I will have to poll the server on repeated intervals to check whether messages are there or not.

From my understanding one of the advantages of using RabbitMQ is you will have listeners which will be activated upon receiving the messages. Any other method which you think is feasible? Can we convert the source code of any one of the open source libraries available in J2SE to J2ME?

Comment: I don't know enough about message queueing architectures to say for sure.  I would guess that they are designed for a server environment, making mobile clients a poor match for their design. Keeping a connection open to avoid your polling problem is normally frowned upon - all mobile platforms offer some sort of 'push' mechanism to get around that, and keep battery life reasonable.  You would want a mobile optimized message-queue client that can take advantage of the push mechanisms, for sure.